# How to change Visual Studio Code error language?

Tags: localization, visual-studio-code

I have Win 10 language set to Czech (I live there) and VS Code to English. But the errors (Problems panel) still show in Czech. [Errors in the problems panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFdco.png) How do I change it to English? I tried deleting some language files in the .NET Framework folder or in the VS Code installation folder.